# How can I loop through a string list of multiple elements and append the string to another? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to Python.
I am trying to append elements of one string to another. The idea is to append different tags to a url. This url is to contain a list (or tuple) of multiple urls that I can access further down in the code. This code is for web scraping purposes.

I have been able to achieve as follows (i.e. this is my current code chunk):

```
def Commodoties(url, headings):
    a = ''
    for h in range(0, len(headings)):
        print(url, '/', headings[h], sep='')
        url = url + headings[h]
    return url, url

headings = ['currencies', 'commodities']
url = 'https://tradingeconomics.com/'

test = Commodoties(url, headings)
print(type(test))
```

Ideally I want to achieve an output along these lines:

```
['https://tradingeconomics.com/currencies', 'https://tradingeconomics.com/commodities']
```

Currently I have achieved the following output:

```
('https://tradingeconomics.com/currenciescommodities', 'https://tradingeconomics.com/currenciescommodities')
```

I have implemented different methods in the Commodoties function, but I have not been able to achieve my desired output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

Comment: check out the posted code and confirm it that's working.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes it is working and is in the desired format thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aj96,  try this code to confirm that's what you want format:

```py
def Commodoties(url, headings):
    result = []
    for h in headings:
        # tmp = url + h
        result.append(url + h)   # simplify 
        print(result)            # can comment out; 
    return result

>>> headings = ['currencies', 'commodities']
>>> url = 'https://tradingeconomics.com/'
>>> test = Commodoties(url, headings)
['https://tradingeconomics.com/currencies']
['https://tradingeconomics.com/currencies', 'https://tradingeconomics.com/commodities']
```

Comment: Add some more notes later for simplifying the logic. First version is to make it easier to read and follow.